# SQL Server 2008 - DB monitoring requirement , what is the best way to do it

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a monitoring requirement where I need to keep checking table data every hour and if it reaches certain counts higher then previous hour, I need to notify certain users. I also need to create some kind of user interface so that user can track counts according to day/weekly too .

I am developer and don't know much about DB except basic use like writing stored procedure / creating table etc. and I searched on internet and found so many options but don't know what will be the best option to go through and if it will fulfill my purpose.

First one is to use SQL Server Reporting Services Enterprise edition. I am not sure if there is a way to compare data from previous one, write logic in it and send email notification in this.

Second one is to write trigger on table and write logic in stored procedure and fire this trigger with stored procedure logic if its possible. And trigger will send email. But then I need to create some kind of interface in application level .

Can someone please help if there is any other better way to do this or what is the best approach in between these two.

Comment: Just a word of warning: I would ***not*** put processing or other longer lasting operations (like creating + sending an e-mail) into a trigger. Those can fire very often and should do the **absolute minimum** possible work - put an entry into another table and that's about it. Do ***not*** put long running / extensive processing into a trigger! That's a sure way to kill your system performance ....

Comment: thanks ! i will keep this in mind during implementation .

Answer (score 0):

Try and read up on the Data Collector:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677248%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: thanks for your comment and link ! I am taking a look right now for data collector.